# I have the latest version of Xcode but I my simulator is not the latest version 17.2. How can I update my simulator?

Tags: flutter, xcode, simulator

iOS 17.2 is not installed. To download and install the platform, open Xcode, select Xcode > Settings > Platforms, and click the GET button for the required platform.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
{ id:68701885-51DD-4C52-8CD6-240BA3CE89A4 }

    Ineligible destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device, error:iOS 17.2 is not installed. To use with Xcode, first download and install the platform }
```

I have downloaded leatest verion of Xcode.

Comment: run     xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS to download latest version then => xcode => settings => platforms and select the  latest version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open Xcode, then enter its Settings:

[image]

And then, in the Platforms tab make sure to get the iOS 17.2 platform software downloaded:

[image]

---

If you for some reason don't see iOS 17.2, but have the latest Xcode (check the requirements [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) or in the screenshot below), you can try to download and install the iOS 17.2 Simulator Runtime manually:

1. Download iOS 17.2 Simulator Runtime DMG from the official Apple website https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg
2. Install it to Xcode with `xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"`

[image]

Comment: but in my platform section. There are devices with a version no higher than 17.0

Comment: Hmm, is it possible you have two Xcodes installed? One that Flutter recognizes and needs the iOS 17.2, and the other one you are describing showing iOS 17.0?

Comment: I have only one installed XCode in my laptop. but there is no device version greater than 17.0. All are 17.0

As soon as I want to update my XCode, my XCode is also on the latest version. So what should I do again? @Albert221

Comment: what macOS version do you have?

Comment: @TarbiyaUzKhusanboev I edited the answer to include the manual installation of the latest Simulator Runtime. Try that

Comment: I am using Sonoma Version 14.2.1 (23C71)

Comment: @Albert221 The same problem with my device too as mentioned by TarbiyaUz Khusanboev I'm using Sonoma 14.3.